# Notation of unordered pairwise combinations between two sets

Tags: notation

given two sets, what would be the mathematical notation to specify the following:

All unordered pairs between members of these sets (so one member from each set, never from the same set).

Thank you!

Comment: If the $2$ sets are $A,B$ one can write: $\{\{n,m\}|n\in A\land m\in B\}$

Comment: Great, thank you very much!